# unable to get text betweent character?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, scrapy, regular-type

I am try to get text "XXXXX" between the characters.like / XXXXX .doc from the url link

I am trying to "item['xxxxx'] = re.search(r'/(.*?)/.doc', item['url']).group(1)"

Here unable to get the text of "XXXXX" is there any correction needed to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dot :

```
re.search(r'/(.*?)/\.doc', item['url']).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is that second slash in there?

Try:

```
re.search(r'/(.*?)\.doc', item['url']).group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine, but we have to add the .group(1) at the end.